# SFML шипение из динамиков при запуске программы

Tags: c++, sfml

Шипят динамики при выполнение этого кода:

```
#include <SFML/Graphics.hpp>

int main()
{
    sf::RenderWindow window(sf::VideoMode(200, 200), "SFML works!");
    sf::CircleShape shape(100.f);
    shape.setFillColor(sf::Color::Green);

    while (window.isOpen())
    {
        sf::Event event;
        while (window.pollEvent(event))
        {
            if (event.type == sf::Event::Closed)
                window.close();
        }

        window.clear();
        window.draw(shape);
        window.display();
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Компилирую вот так: clang++ sfml.cpp -o main -lsfml-graphics -lsfml-window -lsfml-system

Comment: ¿Это случаем не на ноутбуке или каком-то компактном устройстве происходит?

Comment: Да на ноутбуке_

Comment: Ну значит это наводки от подсистемы питания.

Comment: Т.е. она сломана?

Comment: Ну не обязательно сломано, может просто низкое качество изготовления аудиотракта. Экранирование не сделано, вот и гудит от наводок.

Comment: Ещё бывало deb-дистрибутивах что динамики начинали шипеть при проигрование видео

Comment: На Fedora вроде исчезла эта проблема